# Sitecore facet query on key displaying extra non-selected values

Tags: solr, sitecore-query, search-facet

I'm trying to use the `Sitecore Solr` query to retrieve specific `facet` values for a `Sitecore item`. The `facet` is a `checklist filter` and the field is a `tree list` type.

```
var test = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(x => x.ItemId == item.ID).FacetOn(f => f[key]).GetFacets().Categories;
```

However, I end up with extra values which are not selected for that particular item.

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only values that are selected for the items in your search results, you should pass the second parameter to the `.FacetOn()` method like this:

```
.FacetOn(f => f[key], 1)
```

The second parameter specifies the minimum facet count in the found items to be returned. By default this parameter is `0` and it returns all facet categories stored in the index regardless of your `.Where()` search query. If you set this parameter to `1`, it will only return facets where there is at least one item found for each facet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
var selectedValues= context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
  .Where(x => x.ItemId == item.ID)
  .Filter(x => x[key].Contains(item[key]))
  .FacetOn(m => m[key])
  .GetFacets()
  .Categories
  .Where(y=> y.Values.Any(k => k.Name == item[key]));
```